# how to send to stdout in expect script only the matching lines

Tags: expect

i have this simple expect script that sends one command and waits for the response and only some of the lines are matched.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 0

send "user --all\r"
expect {
 timeout { send_user "\nTimeout during command\n"; exp_continue }
 -re "OK  OK  OK  STARTED" { send_user "$expect_out(0,string)\n"; append dbscntl $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue }
 -re "Succeess!" { exp_continue }
 -re ">"
}
exit 0
```

How can I in the regex line to send_out the whole line that was matched the regex expression "OK  OK  OK  STARTED".

In my code with the `send_user "$expect_out(0,string)\n";` gives me only the matched regex expression "OK  OK  OK  STARTED" and not the whole line.

example of lines that would match with the regex expression:

```
0  Running       site1  OK  OK  OK  STARTED
1  Panding       site1  OK  OK  OK  STARTED
2  Running       site1  OK  OK  -   STARTED
3  Stopped       site1  -   OK  OK  STARTED
```

Now I would get:

```
OK  OK  OK  STARTED
OK  OK  OK  STARTED
```

But I would miss the information of the second column.

So, I would like something like:

```
0  Running       site1  OK  OK  OK  STARTED
1  Panding       site1  OK  OK  OK  STARTED
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need expect for this? grep seems the simplest solution

Comment: Using exp_continue in a timeout block does not seem wise.

Comment: To clarify the above questions. 1. this code is only a part of the expect script and the command that is send will ask for credentials, that's why expect. 2. the print out of the command is much more then those lines that i want to match, so i need the exp_continue until i get '>'.

Comment: I provided a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37255077/7552) today: use `-re {(?n).*\mOK\s+OK\s+OK\s+STARTED\r?$}` to match *just the line* ending with that text. `(?n)` enables [newline sensitive matching](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M88).

Comment: I did tried your suggestion, but I don't get it right! How would the line then look like, like this: `-re "(?n).*\mOK\s+OK\s+OK\s+STARTED\r?$" { send_user $expect_out(0,string); append dbscntl $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue }`?

Comment: That looks right. Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script to enable debugging and see why the pattern is not matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions and some tries, I found that this is working in my case `-re "(?n)^DSG.*OK            OK            OK            STARTED(.*)" { send_user "$expect_out(0,string)\n"; append dbscntl $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue }`.

Basically, i had two problems:

1. the regex didn't work with the \m and \s
2. the send_user needed to enclose the $expect_out(0,string) with ""