# Regular expressions in expect

Tags: regex, expect

I just started learning expect scripting.I have been trying to extract the following from my output:

```
core.4046140998.01.10.133211
```

with an expect script using the following command.can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong?I want to get to store this entire string i.e.( core.4046140998.01.10.133211*) in a variable and perform some action with it.

```
expect -re {^(core)\.*} {puts $expect_out(0,string)}
```

Do i have to import any packages in expect to make this work?

Comment: `^(core)\..*(\*)$`

Comment: ok...and what will the output of expect_out(0,string) have?

Comment: it should contain the entire string `core.4046140998.01.10.133211*`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this is expect, "core" may appear at the beginning of a line, but *not at the beginning of the input string*. To demonstrate:

```
$ expect
expect1.1> spawn sh
spawn sh
8043
expect1.2> send "echo core.1234\r"
expect1.3> exp_internal 1
expect1.4> expect -re {^core.*}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '^core.*' is 'core*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^core.*"? Gate "core*"? gate=no
sh-4.3$ echo core.1234
core.1234
sh-4.3$ 
expect: does "sh-4.3$ echo core.1234\r\ncore.1234\r\nsh-4.3$ " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^core.*"? Gate "core*"? gate=yes re=no
expect: timed out
expect1.5> expect -re {(?n)^core.*}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(?n)^core.*' is 'core*'. Activating booster.

expect: does "sh-4.3$ echo core.1234\r\ncore.1234\r\nsh-4.3$ " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "(?n)^core.*"? Gate "core*"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "core.1234\r"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "sh-4.3$ echo core.1234\r\ncore.1234\r"
expect1.6> puts ">>>$expect_out(0,string)<<<"
<<<core.1234
```

Things to note:

- expecting `-re {^core.*}` did not match. We see the "timed out" message
- note what we're attempting to match:

  ```
  expect: does "sh-4.3$ echo core.1234\r\ncore.1234\r\nsh-4.3$ " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "^core.*"? Gate "core*"? gate=yes re=no
  # ............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  It starts with the command I sent, so using a "normal" anchor won't work
- the next thing I expect is `-re {(?n)^core.*}`. This **does** match.

  - the `(?n)` is a little-used [Tcl regex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) instruction that tells the regex engine we want "newline-sensitive" matching.
  - newline-sensitive matching means that `.` will not match a newline and (more relevant here) that `^` can match immediately after a newline within a multi-line string (similarly for `$`)
- note that the output of my `puts` command looks odd. That's due to the carriage return at the end of `$expect_out(0,string)`. Be aware of that, and use `string trim` as required

The take-away lessons here are:

- extracting the output of commands can be hard in expect because the prompt and the sent command can get in the way.
- use expect debugging to see why your patterns aren't matching.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `.` after `\.`:

```
^(core)\..*(\*)$
```

`\.` matches a literal `.` and `.` matches any single character.

Or you can use the non-greedy version:

```
^(core)\.[^*]*(\*)$
```